# UITextView with red color for odd lines and blue for even lines(UITextView with diffrent colors)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I want to show some texts in my application. There are some articles in two languages. For each article, odd paragraphs are comments in first language and even paragraphs are translated comments. Actually it is one of the limits for the specific app that both languages should be available in the same page. Language A should be red and language B should be with blue color.

Is it possible for me to use one UITextView and set different colors for different paragraphs?

I have seen a few topics about text views with multiple colors but none of them were clear enough and I could not find any other helpful posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributed text is what you're looking for, see here: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/format-text-in-ios6-attributed-strings

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to use one UITextView and set different colors for different paragraphs

Yes, it is perfectly possible. Here's some sample code of mine:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p503attributedString/ch23p771attributedStringInLabel/ViewController.m

In that code (set `which` to `4`, I think), we create two paragraphs with two different styles and two different colors, and draw them in a label and a text view.

Comment: Also there's an excellent WWDC 2013 video on drawing styled text.

Comment: Unfortunately just one answer can be accept, +1 for good helping. very thanks.

Comment: No problem! I'm happy to help, and my code example might still help you. Note too that it comes from this longer discussion, which might be useful: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_attributed_strings

Answer (score 0):

`NSAttributedString`s are the tool for the job. They are strings that are specially designed for your user interface, and with that come some special capabilities. You can access the attributed string of your `UITextView` through its `attributedText` property.

```
NSAttributedString *attStr = myTextView.attributedText;
```

Once you have acess to this, you can start messing around with the colors. To do this, you have to apply a special attribute to a certain range.

```
[myTextView.attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                                  value:<firstParagraphColor> 
                                  range:<firstParagraphRange>];

[myTextView.attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                                  value:<secondParagraphColor> 
                                  range:<secondParagraphRange>];
```